# Module not found error while module is present in the directory

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to integrate 2 separate modules. I have following set of directories:

```
testbot
├──├── main.py
│  └── __init__.py
└── face_recognizer
    ├── facenet.py
    ├── detect_face.py
    ├── recognize.py
    └── __init__.py
```

What I'm trying to do is, import the `recognize.py` in `main.py` like this **`from face_recognizer import recognize`** The problem is, when I run the `main` file, it returns error saying *`no module named facenet`*. And points to the line 13 in `recognize.py` where I have imported the `facenet.py` file. But when I run `recognize.py`, it does not give any error and executes successfully. Can anyone help me out how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: Both programs have upto 350 lines of code each, so I couldn't upload the code. Sorry for that.